# cabal - local dependency missing

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am learning cabal. 
Fighting with a "dependencies are missing" error.

I have 2 cabal packages : "base-ext-fana", "xml-fana".
Both are sandboxed. base-ext-fana builds cleanly.
xml-fana should depend on it. So i did `cabal add-source ../base-ext-fana`. I list base-ext-fana in xml-fana.cabal in the "build-depends" section. Still i get :

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base-ext-fana -any
```

on `cabal configure`.

**Investigating myself**

I suspected that i might make a mistake in base-ext-fana, so i replaced it with another package ["idris"] that i know must be correct and still got the same error.

I know i did not misspelled the package path of base-ext-fana in `cabal add-source`, because i let bash complete it and `cabal add-source` did found base-ext-fana.cabal in it. The given path got added to file .cabal-sandbox/add-source-timestamps. I know i did not misspelled the package name base-ext-fana in xml-fana.cabal, becuase i copy-pasted it from base-ext-fana.cabal's name section.

What else may cause the error?

Comment: `cabal configure` will not try to install missing packages, but just look at what is installed when configuring the current package.  You can `cabal install` in the xml-fana directory or `cabal install base-ext-fana ; cabal configure` in the xml-fana directory after having added `base-et-fana` to the sandbox.  In practice you rarely need to manually `cabal configure` and instead almost always `cabal install`.

Comment: So : it is not enough to "add-source" the dependency, but i also have to "install" it?

Comment: I you make it an answer then i accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cabal --require-sandbox install base-ext-fana` solved my problem.

What i missed was that it is not enough to tell cabal where it finds the dependency package [with `cabal sandbox add-source`], but i also have to install it.

This solution was suggested by Thomas M. DuBuisson in a comment.